# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CreateFastString referenced in function _wmain

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I am creating a DLL and providing the entry point to the `FastString` class using  `CreateFastString` function:

`FastString.h`:

```
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)

class FastString
{
    const int m_length;
    char* m_str;

public:
    FastString(const char* str);
    ~FastString();
    int Length()const;
    int Find(const char* str)const;
};

extern "C" FastString* CreateFastString(const char* str);
```

`FastString.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include "FastString.h"

FastString* CreateFastString(const char* str)
{
    return new FastString(str);
}

FastString::FastString(const char* str): m_length(strlen(str)),
                                         m_str(new char[m_length+1])
{}

FastString::~FastString()
{
    delete[] m_str;
}

int FastString::Length()const
{
    return m_length;
}

int FastString::Find(const char* str)const
{
    return 1;
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "FastString.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FastString* str = CreateFastString("Hello Dll");
    std::cout<<"The length is "<<str->Length()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

During compilation, I am getting the following errors:

```
TeatApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CreateFastString referenced in function _wmain
D:\MFC\FastString\Debug\TeatApp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

In the `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` I have provided the path for the `.lib` file.

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to utilize `EXPORT` and `IMPORT` properly.

Comment: @haroogan even if i declare class EXPORT FastString its still not helping.

Comment: I'm preparing an answer for you, hold on.

Answer (score 0):

`config.h`:

```
#define MY_DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define MY_DLL_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)

// Should be defined when MyDLL is built (more details below).
#ifdef MY_DLL_EXPORTS
  #define MY_DLL_PUBLIC MY_DLL_EXPORT
#else
  #define MY_DLL_PUBLIC MY_DLL_IMPORT
#endif

#define MY_DLL_PRIVATE

#ifdef __cplusplus
  #define MY_DLL_FUNCTION extern "C"
#else
  #define MY_DLL_FUNCTION extern
#endif
```

`FastString.h`:

```
#include "config.h"

class MY_DLL_PUBLIC FastString
{
    const int m_length;
    char* m_str;

public:
    FastString(const char* str);
    ~FastString();
    int Length() const;
    int Find(const char* str) const;
};

MY_DLL_FUNCTION FastString* MY_DLL_PUBLIC CreateFastString(const char* str);
```

`FastString.cpp`:

```
#include "FastString.h"

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <string>

FastString* CreateFastString(const char* str)
{
    return new FastString(str);
}

FastString::FastString(const char* str): m_length(strlen(str)),
                                         m_str(new char[m_length+1])
{}

FastString::~FastString()
{
    delete[] m_str;
}

int FastString::Length()const
{
    return m_length;
}

int FastString::Find(const char* str)const
{
    return 1;
}
```

**NOTE:** Build `FastString.cpp` with `MY_DLL_EXPORTS` **defined**, so that the all the symbols marked with `MY_DLL_PUBLIC` are **exported** from the resulting DLL. *"Exported"*, means they will be **visible** for DLL consumers, such as your application. The best practice is to supply this definition during compilation. For example, on MSVC it can be done by adding `/DMY_DLL_EXPORTS` to the compiler invocation.

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "FastString.h"

#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FastString* str = CreateFastString("Hello Dll");
    std::cout<<"The length is "<<str->Length()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** `main.cpp` is your application, which is basically the DLL consumer, therefore, you should **not** define `MY_DLL_EXPORTS` during its compilation, so that all the symbols marked with `MY_DLL_PUBLIC` are **imported** from the consumed DLL.

If your DLL has some **private** functions or classes which should **not** be visible to the DLL consumers, then it's good practice to mark them with `MY_DLL_PRIVATE`. Finally, I didn't see any **[include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)** in your posted code, and I omitted them too in my examples, but beware that you should have them for sure, so don't forget to add them too all of your headers, if they are missing in your real code.